# How to count number of rows of a pandas DataFrame given conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count the number of rows of a pandas DataFrame where the column values of certain columns is True.

For example in the following sample DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

names = {'First_name': ['Jon','Bill','Maria','Emma'], 'Last_name': ['Bobs', 'Vest', 'Gong', 'Hill'],
        'Roll': ['Absent', 'Present', 'Present', 'Absent']}

df = DataFrame(names)
keys = ['Jon', 'Maria', 'Gong', 'Hill', 'Present', 'No']

pattern = r"(?i)" + "|".join(keys)
df['bool1'] = df['First_name'].str.contains(pattern)
df['bool2'] = df['Last_name'].str.contains(pattern)
df
```

output:

```
    First_name  Last_name   Roll    bool1   bool2
0   Jon         Bobs        Absent  True    False
1   Bill        Vest        Present False   False
2   Maria       Gong        Present True    True
3   Emma        Hill        Absent  False   True
```

I want to get a total count of the rows where either the values of the column 'bool1' or the column 'bool2' are True. That is, I should get the final sum equal to 3.

I have tried the following code, but it adds up the rows individually.

```
df.loc[(df['bool1'] == True) | (df['bool2'] == True)].sum()
```

I have also tried an if statement, but it doesn't seem to be correct.

```
if (df['bool1'] == True) and (df['bool2'] == True):
        len(df.index)
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help fix it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want may be the length of filtered dataframe

```
len(df[(df['bool1'] == True) | (df['bool2'] == True)])
# or
len(df[(df['bool1']) | (df['bool2'])])
```

You can try `any` along `bool` like columns

```py
out = df.filter(like='bool').any(axis=1).sum()
```

```
print(out)

3
```

Comment: Thank you for the fix. I also have some other column names in my bigger dataset, where only like='bool' will not work. For example, in the given sample DataFrame, if I needed to also count the rows when the column 'Roll' has the values 'Present' as well. What can I use there instead?

Comment: @Abir Then just extend the condition `df['bool1'] | df['bool2'] | df['Roll'].eq('Present')]`.